# Windows 10 Night Light not turning off / doubling up

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-desktop-computer, thinkcentre

I have a Lenovo ThinkCentre with Windows 10 Pro.
I have been using the Night Light feature every day for a while (so long I don't remember when I started). At first it worked perfectly, a few months ago the timer stopped working so every morning I had/have to open Night Light and turn it on. As of yesterday I am having a new problem.

When I turn on my computer in the morning or if I restart it during the day it seems to double-up the night light filter. If i try to turn the night light filter off completely it only un-doubles it bringing it back to about where I usually have **except** that the cursor is completely unfiltered and does not get the doubled-up effect. (This makes the cursor very bright and irritates my eyes).

When this first happened I made sure to get all the latest windows updates and I updated the Lenovo drivers. This did **not** fix my problem.

So far the only solution I have found is to switch users to an admin user and switch back to my usual user *without* logging out of my user account. If I log out and back in it does not fix the problem.

Edit: To my knowledge, there were no updates that happened before this started. It seems to be out of the blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer to specific to Lenovo computers. I had the same problem and found it is related to a Lenovo software update.

1. Download or use the already installed the Lenovo Vantage software
2. Open the Hardware settings
3. Reset the Eye Care Mode. For me, I actually had to switch it to the "on" setting which removed the screen tint. For you, maybe you have to switch to "off". You will see the difference right away. That should remove the night light feature that is similar to Windows 10.

The Lenovo "Eye Care Mode" was updated early September and may be causing the problem.
source: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/Snipping-Tool-Has-Orange-Tint-Now/td-p/4519013

Comment: I also had to switch it to "on". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to all reports, Night Light is fragile and can break easily.
Several remedies are listed below, including replacing Night Light with a reliable
third-party product.

- Update the graphics driver, as downloaded from the manufacturer website
- Reset the Night light settings by using `regedit` to navigate to
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount`
  and delete the following two keys (take a backup first):

  ```
  $$windows.data.bluelightreduction.bluelightreductionstate
  $$windows.data.bluelightreduction.settings
  ```

  Finally restart your computer.
- Right-click the clock on the system tray, then click Adjust Date/Time and
  Change. Switch the time from AM to PM or vice-versa, and then click Change.
  Repeat again to undo the change.
- Toggle Location service on "Settings > Privacy* and toggle
  Location for This Device and Location Service back and forth.
- Use [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) to automate effects similar to Night Light.
  It is free and highly customizable.

Comment: I tried everything in this list and nothing worked for me.